# How to XSL for-each based on an attribute?

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes, transformation

I need to get all VERS (0 and 1) from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<LIB xmlns:p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <BOOK bnumber="1">
    <CHAPTER cnumber="1">
      <VERS vnumber="1">0</VERS>
      <VERS vnumber="2">1</VERS>
    </CHAPTER>
  </BOOK>
</LIB>
```

I [tried](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/) with this XSL Template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="LIB">
<xsl:for-each select="BOOK">
<xsl:for-each select="CHAPTER"> 
<xsl:value-of select="VERS"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But only got the first VERS (0).

How could I `for-each`? Based on `vnumber` presence, but how?

If you know a good source in plain english, I'm willing to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were using, essentially, one `for-each` too few. There are multiple `VERS`es so you need to iterate over those.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="LIB">
      <xsl:for-each select="BOOK">
        <xsl:for-each select="CHAPTER">
          <xsl:for-each select="VERS[@vnumber]">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, these can all be collapsed down into one `for-each` if you use XPath correctly.

Here is how to iterate over all the `VERS`es that have a `vnumber` attribute:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="LIB/BOOK/CHAPTER/VERS[@vnumber]">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Side note: I think you should study up on how to use templates in XSLT. Presuming that you do want to do something with the LIBs, BOOKs, and CHAPTERS, templates are the way to do that rather than having a deeply nested pyramid like in the first sample above.

Comment: Pardon the nitpick, but `xsl:for-each` does not *iterate*.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Does it not? What term would you prefer?

Comment: Technically, it instantiates a template for each selected node. But you could just say *processes* (that is also term used by the XSLT 2.0 specification).

Comment: Thanks JL! 
I didn't collapse because I'll need to work also on book, chapter (names, numbers).
Is there a good XSL cheat sheet working 80% of the time somewhere? Not another 500 pages guide :)

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 1.0, the `xsl:value-of` instruction returns the string-value of only the **first** node in the selected node-set.

Try instead something like:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="LIB/BOOK/CHAPTER/VERS">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

You did not post your expected result, so I am not sure how you want to separate the returned values.